# WPF Menu icon not showing up when I run my application. They are showing in design view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The icons in my menu are showing in the design view but not at runtime.

Why?

---

I have tried both with and without `pack://application :,,,`

```
<Window x:Class="Aurora4XHelper.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Aurora4XHelper"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="550">
<Grid Name="grid_Main">
    <Menu IsMainMenu="True" x:Name="menu" DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="{Binding ElementName=grid_Main,Path=ActualWidth}">
        <MenuItem Header="File">
            <MenuItem Header="Exit" >
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <Image Source="/Aurora4XHelper;component/Resources/Icons/Exit.png" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Header="Design">
            <MenuItem Header="Missile">
                <MenuItem Header="Missile">
                    <MenuItem.Icon>
                        <Image Source="pack://application :,,,/Aurora4XHelper;component/Resources/Icons/Missile.png" />
                    </MenuItem.Icon>
                </MenuItem>
                <MenuItem Header="MIRV" />
                <MenuItem Header="Bouy" />
                <MenuItem Header="Mine" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Sensor" />
            <MenuItem Header="Ship" />
            <MenuItem Header="Terraforming"/>
        </MenuItem>
    </Menu>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the `/Aurora4XHelper;component/` part and just put `<Image Source="Resources/Icons/Exit.png" />` instead.
Also make sure the BuildAction of the png file is set to Resource.

Comment: Thank you. Just using `<Image Source="Resources/Icons/Exit.png" />` Worked

Comment: Also, if this doesn't work for you (after setting Build Action to Ressource), try Build (menu) **Clean Solution**, and then rerun (F5) - did it for me : )